# set default schema for a sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, schema

Is there a way to set the schema for a query so that in the rest of the query I can refer to tables just by their name without prepending them with a schema name?

For instance, I would like to do something like this:

```
Use [schemaName]
select * from [tableName]
```

as opposed to this:

```
select * from [schemaName].[tableName]
```

Comment: Point to your Database Name and select new query in SQLMS. Use DBNAME; Select * from [Tablename] is correct.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

A quick google pointed me to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx). It explains that from SQL Server 2005 onwards you can set the default schema of a user with the `ALTER USER` statement. Unfortunately, that means that you change it permanently, so if you need to switch between schemas, you would need to set it every time you execute a stored procedure or a batch of statements. Alternatively, you could use the technique described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569690/can-i-set-a-default-schema-for-within-a-stored-procedure/1570121#1570121).

If you are using SQL Server 2000 or older [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387.aspx) explains that users and schemas are then equivalent. If you don't prepend your table name with a schema\user, SQL Server will first look at the tables owned by the current user and then the ones owned by the `dbo` to resolve the table name. It seems that for all other tables you must prepend the schema\user.

Comment: This got me to the answer I needed.  Turns out that Default Schema is ignored if the user is a member of the SysAdmin fixed server role.  It just uses dbo...

Answer (score 24):

I do not believe there is a "per query" way to do this. (You can use the `use` keyword to specify the *database* - not the schema - but that's technically a separate query as you have to issue the `go` command afterward.)

Remember, in SQL server fully qualified table names are in the format:

> [database].[schema].[table]

In SQL Server Management Studio you can configure all the defaults you're asking about.

- You can set up the default `database` on a per-user basis (or in your connection string):

  > Security > Logins > (right click) user > Properties > General
- You can set up the default `schema` on a per-user basis (but I do not believe you can configure it in your connection string, although if you use `dbo` that is always the default):

  > Security > Logins > (right click) user > Properties > User Mapping > Default Schema

In short, if you use `dbo` for your schema, you'll likely have the least amount of headaches.

Answer (score 11):

Very old question, but since google led me here I'll add a solution that I found useful:

Step 1. Create a user for each schema you need to be able to use. E.g. "user_myschema"

Step 2. Use EXECUTE AS to execute the SQL statements as the required schema user.

Step 3. Use REVERT to switch back to the original user.

Example:
Let's say you have a table "mytable" present in schema "otherschema", which is not your default schema. Running "SELECT * FROM mytable" won't work.

Create a user named "user_otherschema" and set that user's default schema to be "otherschema".

Now you can run this script to interact with the table:

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'user_otherschema';
SELECT * FROM mytable
REVERT
```

The revert statements resets current user, so you are yourself again.

Link to EXECUTE AS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: so there is a default schema for every user, did not know that until know. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What I sometimes do when I need a lot of table names I'll just get them plus their schema from the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` system table:
value

```
select  TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME in
(*select your table names*)
```

Answer (score 1):

SETUSER could work, having a user, even an orphaned user in the DB with the default schema needed.  But SETUSER is on the legacy not supported for ever list.  So a similar alternative would be to setup an application role with the needed default schema, as long as no cross DB access is needed, this should work like a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Try setuser. Example

```
declare @schema nvarchar (256)
set @schema=(
  select top 1 TABLE_SCHEMA
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  where TABLE_NAME='MyTable'
)
if @schema<>'dbo' setuser @schema
```

Comment: I don't think this does what the OP is asking for. [SETUSER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186297.aspx) seems to be to change the current user, not the current schema. Also, the linked documentation implies it's deprecated...

Answer (score -3):

Another way of adding schema dynamically or if you want to change it to something else

```
DECLARE @schema AS VARCHAR(256) = 'dbo.'
--User can also use SELECT SCHEMA_NAME() to get the default schema name


DECLARE @ID INT

declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = 'EXEC ' + @schema +'spSelectCaseBookingDetails @BookingID = '  + CAST(@ID AS NVARCHAR(10))
```

No need to cast @ID if it is nvarchar or varchar

```
execute (@SQL)
```

Answer (score -4):

For Oracle, please use this simple command:

`ALTER SESSION SET current_schema = your-schema-without-quotes;`

Comment: Your answer is off-topic. The question is exclusively for MS SQL Server. Also, Oracle schemas are nothing like SQL Server schemas.