# How can I write queries without having to specify the schema name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I can only get data like this format:

```
SELECT * FROM Abc.ACADEMY
```

Where `Abc` is a username, `ACADEMY` is a table name, and `ABC` is also my schema name

What I want to be able to write this as:

```
SELECT * FROM ACADEMY
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Always specifying the schema name is a good habit, while relying on implicit schemas is an anti-pattern.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/57787608/4251431
EXECUTE AS USER = 'user_otherschema';

Answer (score 4):

If you set the user's default schema to `[abc]` (or whatever it actually is), you won't have to specify that schema name as part of the full table name anymore.

```
-- before 
SELECT * FROM abc.ACADEMY
GO

ALTER USER userName WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = abc
GO

-- after 
SELECT * FROM ACADEMY
GO
```

Comment: @UfukTÜKENMEZ What *exactly* did you try? What doesn't work about it?

Comment: @UfukTÜKENMEZ Are you actually executing the code as that user *in SQL* (i.e. connected as that User ID in the connection string)? If so, it should work. If you do specify any schema name, it will assume you are looking for tables in the current user's default schema.

Comment: Yes i executed the code as that user. It should work to me.. I'm still trying to solve the problem. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @UfukTÜKENMEZ Try `SELECT SCHEMA_NAME()` to verify that the default schema name is set. If everything worked as intended, it should return `abc` (or whatever schema you set).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it !!

Here is the solution:

Changing of Schema owner which has been set before as my user name to "dbo" solved my problem.

http://www.ufuktukenmez.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Adsiz.png

Thank you for helping.

Comment: url not works...

Answer (score -2):

This is how I usually do it

Use ABC

select * from Academy

Comment: This answer is wrong. "Use ABC" is solely intented for switching database.