# Set default schema for stored procedure/function call

Tags: sql-server

I'm experimenting with T-SQL syntax. If most db objects for specific task are located in separate `my_schema` (not `dbo.`), how to reduce the "noise" in SQL statements related to lots of `my_schema.` prefixes?

With approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942023/set-default-schema-for-a-sql-query), I resolved the case for tables.

However, for calling stored procedures and functions, it is still required to add the prefix `my_schema.`.

Is there a way to call `my_schema.stored_proc` just with

```
exec stored_proc
```

without any prefix `my_schema.`?

Comment: Yes, you *can* reference objects without the schema, when you omit it then the default schema for the `USER` connected is used. Is is advisable? No. [Bad Habits to Kick : Avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)

Comment: Schema qualification is not "noise" and can improve performance.

Comment: Thanks for the article, @Larnu. I walked through steps there, but still can not run for e.g. ```select my_func()``` -> it requeres prefix. At the same time I've achieved ability to run ```select * from my_table```, without prefix. (it works the same as my current approach ```alter user @user_name with default_schema = @schema_name```) Looks like with approach from the artical is not possible to run programming objects without prefix. In the artical there is no references about it. Did you try it with stored procedures/functions? Would you show example?

Comment: @DanGuzman, completely agree with you. Thats why I used quotes for "noise"; I mean syntax "noise" in code text -> not real noise.
And actually, in artical provided by Larnu, there influence onto performance is highlighted as well: "... I just wanted to suggest that you get into the habit of using the prefix whenever you create or reference objects, even if you are currently only using objects in dbo. You might thank me later."
However, this my case is an experiment ;)

Comment: `select my_func()` that **isn't** a procedure, it's a function. For user defined functions you **must** provide the schema; it is non-optional.

Comment: Expected that it works similar for any type of code objects. But it is not (.
@Larnu, thanks for info.
Anyway will finish check of ```exec stored_proc``` later.