# Selecting data from a different schema within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[setIdentifier](@oldIdentifierName as varchar(50), @newIdentifierName as varchar(50))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @old_id as int;
    DECLARE @new_id as int;

    SET @old_id = (SELECT value FROM Configuration WHERE id = @oldIdentifierName);
    SET @new_id = (SELECT value FROM Configuration WHERE id = @newIdentifierName);

    IF @old_id IS NOT NULL AND @new_id IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Customer
        SET type = @new_id
        WHERE type = @old_id;
    END; 
END
```

[...]

```
EXECUTE dbo.setIdentifier '1', '2';
```

What this does is create a stored procedure that accepts two parameters which it then uses to update a Customer table.

The problem is that the entire script above runs within a schema other than "dbo". Let's just assume the schema is "company1". And when the stored procedure is called, I get an error from the SELECT statement, which says that the Configuration table cannot be found. I'm guessing this is because MS SQL by default looks for tables within the same schema as the location of the stored procedure, and not within the calling context.

My question is this:

1. Is there some option or parameter or switch of some kind that will
   tell MS SQL to look for tables in the "caller's default schema" and
   not within the schema that procedure itself is stored in?
2. If not,
   what would you recommend? I don't really want to prefix the tables
   with the schema name, because it would be kind of unflexible to do
   that. So I'm thinking about using dynamic sql (and the schema_name()
   function which returns the correct value even within the procedure),
   but I am just not experienced enough with MS SQL to construct the
   proper syntax.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569690/can-i-set-a-default-schema-for-within-a-stored-procedure/1570121#1570121 for a potential solution.

Comment: Will there ever be an option to change the Schema of the `Configuration` table? The schema is as much part of the name as the "Configuration" string. Hardcoding can be a problem, but so can [Softcoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softcoding)

Comment: Well. Semantics isn't it. Is the username and password also part of the configuration then? In my experience application code will be accessing tables by name though connections, so table names can be hardcoded. But the schema could very easily change, and I would like this to be possible without doing any code modifications (and an sql script counts as code in my book)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing the schema name to my script as a property on the command line for the "sqlcmd" command. Like this:

```
C:/> sqlcmd -vSCHEMANAME=myschema -imysqlfile
```

In the SQL script I can then access this variable like this:

```
SELECT * from $(SCHEMANAME).myTable WHERE.... etc
```

Not quite as flexible as dynamic sql, but "good enough" as it were.

Thanks all for taking time to respond.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a tad more efficient to explicitly specify the schema name. And generally speaking, schema's are mainly used to divide a database into logical area's. I would not anticipate on tables schema-hopping often.

Regarding your question, you might want to have a look at the '[execute as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx)' documentation on msdn, since it allows to explicitly control your execution context.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I actually tried the execute as, but the table could not be found even when I used "owner" or "caller".