# Dynamic change schema in SQL procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a database with multiple schemas. In every schema I got table called [Logs], so my database tables looks like:

```
[s1].[Logs]
[s2].[Logs]
[s3].[Logs]
...
[sN].[Logs]
```

Every day I would like to run stored procedure, which will do same operations on every above table. Is there a way to pass schema name into stored procedure? I am using SQL on Azure.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1570121/1048425) could be of some use to you.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not - unless the SP Uses then dynamic SQL to execute some SQL String you constructed in the SP.

This happens via the sp_executesql stored procedure

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx

has more information.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has a few undocumented procedures that perform "foreach" operations on tables (`sp_msforeachtable`) and databases (`sp_msforeachdb`). Both of these rely on another undocumented proc called `sp_msforeachworker` which you might be able to exploit to create a foreachschema type of routine.  Theres an article (reg required) [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Administration/sp_msforeachworker/711/) that demonstrates this approach.

That said, its unlikely Azure supports anything of these, so you might have to fashion your own using a crude loop:

```
declare @schemas table (i int identity(1,1), name sysname);
insert into @schemas
    select name from sys.schemas where name like 's[0-9]%';

declare @i int, @name sysname, @cmd nvarchar(max);
select @i = min(i) from @schemas;

while @i is not null
begin

    select @name = name from @schemas where i = @i;

    set @cmd = replace(N'select count(*) from [{0}].[Logs];', '{0}', @name);
    print @cmd;

    --exec(@cmd);
    select @i = min(i) from @schemas where i > @i;
end
```